# async.js parallel not working correctly

Tags: node.js, async.js

I have the following code:

```
               async.parallel({
                    one: function(callback) { gps_helper.get_gps(PEMSID, conn, start, stop, function(fullResults){
                        callback(fullResults);
                    }) },     //query for new dataSet
                    two: function(callback) { admin.getTh(function(gpsThresholds){
                        callback(gpsThresholds);
                    }) }
                },                                      
                function(results){

                    console.log(results);
                    console.log('emitting GPS...');
                    socket.emit('GPS', {gpsResults: results.one, thresholds: results.two, PEMSID: PEMSID, count: count, length: PEMSToDisplay.length, checked: checked});     
                    count++;      
                });
```

This isn't working, my console displays the first query that finishes in the callback as `results`. There also is no `{one: fullResults, two: gpsThresholds}` formatting in the output, it's just displaying the callback value form the respective functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument of the async callback should be the error object, so it should really be returning `null` if everything was ok

```
function(err, results){
     console.log(results);
     console.log('emitting GPS...');
     socket.emit('GPS', {gpsResults: results.one, thresholds: results.two, PEMSID: PEMSID, count: count, length: PEMSToDisplay.length, checked: checked});     
     count++;      
 });
```

same goes for the callbacks

```
callback(null, fullResults);
```

etc, to pass `null` to the error handler the async callback.
There's an example in the [documentation](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) showing exactly how it's done.